# Overleaf incompatible with journal's document class?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, document-classes

I'm trying to format a journal article for publication. The journal has their own [latex document class](https://acousticalsociety.org/preparing-latex-manuscripts/) `JASA` and I just cannot get my .bib file to register in that document class on Overleaf:

```
 \documentclass[preprint]{JASA}
```

I've tried every imaginable combination of packages but my citation entries still appear as [?] in the PDF. I can't even get the sample .tex document that comes with the package to work on Overleaf. I usually use Natbib on Overleaf, but this document class employs Bibtex, which [should function](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/532-creating-and-managing-bibliographies-with-bibtex-on-overleaf) just fine.  Is Overleaf just incompatible with this document class?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your issue appears to be specific to Overleaf. Have you contacted the Overleaf HelpDesk? I hear their LaTeX support staff is top-notch.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. I downloaded the class from https://acousticalsociety.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/JASA-LaTeX-v2019.zip, I created a new project in Overleaf and uploaded all the files, I edited `JASAtemplate.tex` in Overleaf to add `\cite{newspaperSamp}
\bibliography{sampbib}` just before `\end{document}` and clicked on Compile. Then I got a proper citation (Gordinier, 2015 in this case) in the PDF.